# Es posible enviar un objeto vacio desde PHP?

Tags: php, java

Me gustaria poner un poco de trasfondo a este sencillo problema, así que dire lo siguiente:

Como tal este problema lo maneje de una manera diferente en su momento, siendo que cuando me tocase enviar un objeto vacio al cliente lo que hacia era que en vez de tratar de enviar algo como esto:

```
{"nombre":"","edad":-2,"colecciones":{}}
```

En su lugar debia pensar en enviar algo como esto:

```
{"nombre":"","edad":-2,"colecciones":{"F":false}}
```

Esto debido a que en `PHP` la forma en la que la funcion `json_encode` codifica **posibles** objetos es mediante llaves asociativas, es decir, `PHP` interpreta que se trata de un **objeto** y **NO** de un array cuando hay claves asociativas ligadas al array.

Para entendernos mejor, esto es lo que yo haria en `PHP` para tratar de conseguir algo similar a esto:

```
{"nombre":"","edad":-2,"colecciones":{}}
```

**PHP**:

```
$ob = json_encode(["nombre" => "", "edad" => -2, "colecciones" => []]);
echo $ob;
```

Porsupuesto el problema de esto es que el resultado final es:

```
{"nombre":"","edad":-2,"colecciones":[]}
```

y **NO**:

```
{"nombre":"","edad":-2,"colecciones":{}}
```

Entonces me surgia la duda de como podia declarar un objeto vació usando `json_encode`, pues se supone que los objetos se construyen en base a llaves asociativas. pero claro... en un objeto vacio no habria **ninguna llave**, por lo tanto **PHP** siempre interpretara `[]` como un arreglo vacio, y no como un **objeto vacio** a la hora de codificar.

Esto por supuesto lo solucione colocando como respuesta en la llave colecciones como minimo una llave, esta llave seria totalmente inutil y seria totalmente random, pero obligaria a que **PHP** a interpretar **colecciones** como un `objeto`, de esta manera no tendria problemas del lado del cliente.

Esto es debido a que me encontraba utilizando en este caso `Java` un lenguaje de programación de tipado fuerte como cliente, adicionalmente implementando la libreria `volley`, por ende la flexibilidad era entre poca y nula, y obviamente podrian haber variaciones en los resultados (a vecez habria mas de un elemento en `colecciones`, como tambien a vecez no habria ninguno, en cuyo caso generaba errores debido a la interpretación del tipo del elemento en el cliente de manera erronea).

Este problema me puso a pensar entonces si habia alguna forma de generar un objeto vació utilizando la función `json_encode`, para asi no tener que hacer cosas como esta cosa tan horrible de aqui:

```
{"nombre":"","edad":-2,"colecciones":{"F":false}}
```

Hay forma de devolver un objeto vacio?, y si es asi como se haria con `json_encode`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595627/best-way-to-create-an-empty-object-in-json-with-php

Comment: Independientemente de la duda que planteas aquí: crear un objeto vacío. Me pregunto, ¿qué sentido tiene esto en una comunicación cliente/servidor? Mi pregunta surge porque sospecho que de fondo lo que hay es un error de enfoque. ¿Por qué y/o para qué el servidor debería crear un objeto vacío? ¿Hay algo que justifique ese comportamiento? Generalmente, ante errores y demás lo que hace el servidor es construir un objeto con una clave `error` o algo así, y el cliente, en la respuesta, verificaría si la misma tiene o no una clave `error` para actuar en consecuencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la clase StdClass para crear un objeto vacío.

Por ejemplo

```
echo json_encode(['key' => new StdClass()]);
// {"key":{}}
```

Puedes revisar la documentación aquí https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.classes.php